# Android Youtube API INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, youtube

Im trying to play Youtube video from my app via YouTube Android API:

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
                  this, 
                  getString(R.string.youtube_api_key), 
                  "cdgQpa1pUUE");

startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But in onActivityResult I get INTERNAL_ERROR.